# Problem while fetching milliseconds from Date

Tags: java, android, date

I have a date in string format as `25 November 2010` and I am trying to fetch the milliseconds of that date, for that I have written the below code:

```
strDateSelcted = "25 November 2010" // Actually I am receiving date in this format
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy"); 
 try {
    Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(strDateSelcted);

        insertEventtoCalendar(dateObj.getTime());   // Actually insert an event onto the native calendar

  } catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

But, when I try to run the application,it creates an event a day before the date inserted, i.e. For 25 November 2010 it inserts event on 24 November 2010 and For 27 November 2010 it inserts event on 26 November 2010, and same.

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: I didn't get you ,you  are trying to fetch millis from `25 November 2010 ` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is useful for you but I think that in SimpleDateFormat, MMM gives the month like that : Nov and not November...

Comment: @org.life.java ya you got exactly, i want to get milliseconds of particular date (here, i am having a date in String variable)

Comment: @Sephy thanx, i corrected MMM with MMMM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the timezone used by the date formatter: call the setTimeZone method
e.g.

```
curFormater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Answer (score 2):

For one, your date pattern is wrong, use `dd MMMM yyyy`. `MMM` parses & returns `Nov` (not `November`).

<strike>Also, since there is no millisecond provided in your date string, the millisecond will be set to `0`.</strike>

Seeing that Jon Skeet updated me with the question, it might be timezone issue (as he mentioned). Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Test code:

```
/**
 * 
 */

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * @author The Elite Gentleman
 *
 */
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            String date = "25 November 2010";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
            Date d = sdf.parse(date);
            System.out.println(d.getTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Value: `1290636000000`

Comment: By "milliseconds of that date" I believe the OP means "milliseconds since January 1st 1970 UTC" in the normal way for java.util.Date.

Comment: @Elite thanx for the support, i have correct MMM to MMMM,and also tried your way of Calendar, but now i am getting Milliseconds as 0 (zero)

Comment: @PM - Paresh Mayani  In above code try `c.getTimeInMillis() ;`

Comment: @org.life.java same result as 1290277800000 for 21 November 2010, but insertion of event is made on 20 November 2010

Comment: @Elite After setting the c.getTimeInMillis() , i am getting 1290623400000 for the 25 November 2010

Comment: @PM - Paresh Mayani, it gives me `Wed Nov 24 20:30:00 CAT 2010`. Do you know how your timezone was set on Android?

Comment: @Elite I dont know how to set, but as @gcoghlan suggested, i have tried with curFormater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); , i done it this way !!

Comment: @PM, you can do exactly what @gcoghlan said, yes.

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Note that a Date-Time without a timezone represents a local Date-Time which may be different for a different timezone e.g. today, it is 31<sup>st</sup> May 2021 in my timezone, `Europe/London` whereas 1<sup>st</sup> June 2021 in `Australia/Sydney`. So, in order to represent a moment (i.e. an instantaneous point on the timeline in [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc)), Java provides a class called [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) which you can convert to other Date-Time types e.g.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();

        LocalDate todayUK = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")).toLocalDate();
        LocalDate todaySydney = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney")).toLocalDate();
        System.out.println(todayUK);
        System.out.println(todaySydney);

        LocalDateTime nowUK = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")).toLocalDateTime();
        LocalDateTime nowSydney = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney")).toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(nowUK);
        System.out.println(nowSydney);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-05-31
2021-06-01
2021-05-31T16:22:40.418214
2021-06-01T01:22:40.418214
```

So, you need to choose a timezone. Most digital operations are based on the UTC (timezone offset, `+00:00` hours).

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMMM u", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("25 November 2010", dtf);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);

        long millis = instant.toEpochMilli();
        System.out.println("Milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT: " + millis);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2010-11-25T00:00:00Z
Milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT: 1290643200000
```

The `Z` in the sample output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for a zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Now, pass `millis` to your `insertEventtoCalendar`:

```
insertEventtoCalendar(millis);
```

**Note:** For any reason you need an object of `java.util.Date`, you can get it from this `Instant` as

```
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### What went wrong with your code?

You tried parsing the date string without setting a timezone and therefore, `SimpleDateFormat` used your JVM's timezone to parse the date string, giving you a moment/instant corresponding to the start-of-the-day on **25 November 2010** in your timezone. To fix the problem, set the desired `Timezone` (e.g. UTC) to the `SimpleDateFormat` instance before parsing i.e.

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
curFormater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
```

**Two more important notes:**

1. Use `MMMM` instead of `MMM` for the full monthname.
2. [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Do we have enums defined in some class for strings `Europe/London`, `Etc/UTC` etc?

Comment: There are no enums defined for the timezones, probably they are in huge numbers. However, we can get the list of timezone names by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly a time zone issue. Check which time zone your `SimpleDateFormat` is using, and the one your phone is using to display the event.

For diagnostic purposes I suggest you log the result of `dateObj.getTime()` and you can check *exactly* what that means on a desktop machine.

Comment: i have tried to Log it, it has returned 1290277800000 for 21 November 2010

Comment: `1290277800000` represents the instance in time that is Sat, 20 Nov 2010 18:30:00 GMT.  So it's a time zone issue as Jon says.  Part of the problem is that you're trying to represent a *date*, but you're storing an *instance in time* which is represented as GMT in the database (and truncated accordingly).

Comment: @PM: That's Saturday Nov 20 18:30:00 UTC. Are you in a time zone which is 5 1/2 hours ahead of UTC, by any chance? :)

Comment: @Jon ya Currently i am testing an application with India TimeZone (5:30) hours

Comment: @Jon How can i come out from the above situation, is there any way ?? because application can be used from any country so please show me a correct way

Comment: @PM - Paresh Mayani: Well, it *may* be that you want to set the time zone of the `SimpleDateFormat` to the current system default time zone... or it *may* be that you want to set it to UTC. We don't know enough about what you're trying to do to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Locale.getDefault()` when Your using `SimpleDateFormat`.I hope it may solve your problem.