# Facing problem While Converting Date to MilliSeconds

Tags: java, android

In my **Android Application**, I am trying to convert Date/Time to Milliseconds, check the below code:

```
public long Date_to_MilliSeconds(int day, int month, int year, int hour, int minute)
{

       Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
       c.set(year, month, day, hour, minute, 00);

        return c.getTimeInMillis();

}
```

**Problem:** I am getting 1290455340800(Nov 22 14:49:00 EST 2010) for Nov 22 19:49:00 EST 2010 (i.e. 5 hours back)

**`FYI, I am Currently in Indian TimeZone, but application can be executed from any country. so How do i exact Convert the date/time into the Milliseconds?`**

Comment: Is it the part of the same problem from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275823/problem-while-fetching-milliseconds-from-date/4275873#4275873?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Is probably causing the issue. There is no need to set the TimeZone as the current default is used.

Comment: ya you are right, i dont need to set the TimeZone, i have removed the TimeZone "UTC" and now its working fine, Actually i was trying to insert an Event into the Calendar, so now Time of event is inserting properly

Comment: @PM - Paresh Mayani No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're calling `Date_to_MilliSeconds(22, 10, 2010, 19, 49)`. Your code explicitly uses UTC, so it's going to treat whatever you pass it in as UTC.

Just like your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275823/problem-while-fetching-milliseconds-from-date) (which makes me tempted to close this as a duplicate) it's unclear what you're really trying to do.

If you want to provide a local time to your method, you need to specify a local time zone. If you need to use a local time in the user's time zone, try setting the time zone to `TimeZone.getDefault()` - although I'd expect that to be the default anyway. If you want to provide a UTC time to your method, you need to specify a UTC time zone (as you are here).

What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: ya jon you are right, i am moving round and round with the "Timing" issue, what do i do to make an application as such as it will not get a Timing Issue??

Comment: @PM - Paresh: You need to be a lot clearer about what you actually mean at each step - what your input is (a local time in a particular time zone? a local time with no specific time zone? a UTC time?) and what output you need.

Answer (score 1):

In this piece of code, you are getting the amount of milliseconds since 01/01/1970 00:00 in your timezone for Nov 22 19:49:00 EST 2010 in UTC timezone. Why are you setting timezone to UTC?

Answer (score 1):

The 5 hours difference is the difference between UTC and EST. You can use `DateFormat.parse()` to parse the input date if it's a string. Or you can use the code above and pass the desired timezone in `c.setTimeZone()` -- put in EST instead of UTC.

Comment: made my life!! but let me know, will i get problem while i will test it from other country than india?

Comment: This should have nothing to do with the timezone you run the application in. If the source datetime has a timezone it will be parsed by `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` or you will use that in `setTimezone()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this:

```
public String timeToString(long time, String format) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.getDefault());
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    return sdf.format(time + TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset()
            + TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings());
}
```

I think it solves the TimeZone problems.